# Most optimal match-up

Tags: algorithm, optimization

Let's assume you're a baseball manager. And you have N pitchers in your bullpen (N<=14) and they have to face M batters (M<=100). Also to mention you know the strength of each of the pitchers and each of the batters. For those who are not familiar to baseball once you brought in a relief pitcher he can pitch to k consecutive batters, but once he's taken out ofthe game he cannot come back.

For each pitcher the probability that he's gonna lose his match-ups is given by (sum of all batter he will face)/(his strength). Try to minimize these probabilities, i.e. try to maximize your chances of winning the game.

For example we have 3 pitchers and they have to face 3 batters. The batters' stregnths are:

```
10 40 30
```

While the strength of your pitchers is:

```
40 30 3
```

The most optimal solution would be to bring the strongest pitcher to face the first 2 batters and the second to face the third batter. Then the probability of every pitcher losing his game will be:

50/40 = 1.25 and 30/30 = 1

So the probability of losing the game would be 1.25 (This number can be bigger than 100).

How can you find the optimal number? I was thinking to take a greedy approach, but I suspect whether it will always hold. Also the fact that the pitcher can face unlimited number of batters (I mean it's only limited by M) poses the major problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

Probabilities must be in the range [0.0, 1.0] so what you call a probability can't be a probability. I'm just going to call it a score and minimize it.

I'm going to assume for now that you somehow know the order in which the pitchers should play.

Given the order, what is left to decide is how long each pitcher plays. I think you can find this out using dynamic programming. Consider the batters to be faced in order. Build an NxM table best[pitchers, batter] where best[i, j] is the best score you can make considering just the first j batters using the first i pitchers, or HUGE if it does not make sense.

best[1,1] is just the score for the best pitcher against the first batter, and best[1,j] doesn't make sense for any other values of j.

For larger values of i you work out best[i,j] by considering when the last change of pitcher could be, considering all possibilities (so 1, 2, 3...i). If the last change of pitcher was at time t, then look up best[t, j-1] to get the score up to the time just before that change, and then calculate the a/b value to take account of the sum of batter strengths between time t+1 and time i. When you have considered all possible times, take the best score and use it as the value for best[i, j]. Note down enough info (such as the last time of pitcher change that turned out to be best) so that once you have calculated best[N, M], you can trace back to find the best schedule.

You don't actually know the order, and because the final score is the maximum of the a/b value for each pitcher, the order does matter. However, given a separation of players into groups, the best way to assign pitchers to groups is to assign the best pitcher to the group with the highest total score, the next best pitcher to the group with the next best total score, and so on. So you could alternate between dividing batters into groups, as described above, and then assigning pitchers to groups to work out the order the pitchers really should be in - keep doing this until the answer stops changing and hope the result is a global optimum. Unfortunately there is no guarantee of this.

I'm not convinced that your score is a good model for baseball, especially since it started out as a probability but can't be. Perhaps you should work out a few examples (maybe even solving small examples by brute force) and see if the results look reasonable.

Comment: Actually the score is calculated as max{50/40,30/30} and not (50/40)*(30/30)

Comment: This appears to make the problem more difficult, at least for this approach. I have patched it up as best as I can.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to approach this problem is via http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branch_and_bound.

With branch and bound you need some way to describe partial answers, and you need some way to work out a value V for a given partial answer, such that no way of extending that partial answer can possibly produce a better answer than V. Then you run a tree search, extending partial answers in every possible way, but discarding partial answers which can't possibly be any better than the best answer found so far. It is good if you can start off with at least a guess at the best answer, because then you can discard poor partial answers from the start. My other answer might provide a way of getting this.

Here a partial answer is a selection of pitchers, in the order they should play, together with the number of batters they should pitch to. The first partial answer would have 0 pitchers, and you could extend this by choosing each possible pitcher, pitching to each possible number of batters, giving a list of partial answers each mentioning just one pitcher, most of which you could hopefully discard.

Given a partial answer, you can compute the (total batter strength)/(Pitcher strength) for each pitcher in its selection. The maximum found here is one possible way of working out V. There is another calculation you can do. Sum up the total strengths of all the batters left and divide by the total strengths of all the pitchers left. This would be the best possible result you could get for the pitchers left, because it is the result you get if you somehow manage to allocate pitchers to batters as evenly as possible. If this value is greater than the V you have calculated so far, use this instead of V to get a less optimistic (but more accurate) measure of how good any descendant of that partial answer could possibly be.